# How can I make my lapotronic charge pad charge faster?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-industrialcraft

It takes ages to charge my GraviChestPlate while standing on a Lapotronic charge pad. Are there upgrades that will make it faster? Overclocker? Efficiency?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use overclocker upgrades (up to 16 per upgrade slot) to make it work faster. With overclockers, however, the charge pad will use more energy. To offset this, you can use efficiency upgrades.

Comment: I have 12 in one slot at the moment, should I spread them out?

Comment: @fredley No but you can stack 12 in another slot, and another, and another... Just make sure you actually can supply that much power.

Comment: @Unionhawk I believe the 4-per-slot limit is one of the myriad tweaks GregTech makes to other mods to stretch out the "mid game" and make "late-game" content harder to get/more desirable.